# Typescript how to tell that element is checkbox, so element.checked is not red underlined

Tags: checkbox, typescript

I am checking for input type of some element, fe checkbox in TS. Now I am sure that I have element that is checkbox, so this element should have property checked. But if I simply do

```
element: HTMLElement
if (element.InputType.toLowerCase() == "checkbox"){
    element.checked = true;
}
```

than it is working, but element.checked is red underlined. I think that I simply have to retype from HTMLElement to something like CheckboxElement, but did not find anything suitable for this conversion. How to get rid of this ? I have facing this also in case of element.value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "checkbox" element type as it is just an "input" element with type `checkbox`. You could use/assert with the type `HTMLInputElement` which is an extension of `HTMLElement`:

```
var element: HTMLInputElement;
//... You still need to do all the null checks as necessary
//The below check may be irrelevant depending upon what you are actually doing. 
//But i am just adding here to show that you need to refer to the property "type" and 
//not "InputType"
if (element.type.toLowerCase() == "checkbox") { 
     element.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: +1 and just for clarity, he doesn't need to do the test above when using `HTMLInputElement` ... now he can simply use the `checked` property:  `(if element.checked`) { ...`

Comment: @SunilD. Thx, OP may remove it perhaps it is a part of code which sets default based on the element's input type and checkbox happens to be one of them. Just to clarify your statement - `he doesn't need to do the test above when using HTMLInputElement` asserting with a specific type with typescript does not ensure any runtime safety though the specific check here may be irrelevant and you are right about that.

Comment: Thanks for help. One more thing. Suppose I have listener on change event, now I would like to check type of input `<HTMLElement>event.target).type) == "password"` now sure this can be changed to `<HTMLInputElement>event.target).type) == "password"` but the problem is that change event can be fired on  <keygen> element, which I do not know exactly what it is, but I assume that it do not have property `type`. Is there safe way how to use casting in TS ? Only things that come to my mind is that before this I will check that tag is input. @Sunil D.

Comment: @PetrKrčmárik There is no type casting, you can only assert something to be of some type and it is only during compile time (transpile time) and not at run time. For any null checks etc you would need to do that checks explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

The `if` statement is not necessary as others have already stated. However, there are several ways how to make compiler happy:

```
// 1st (best variant in my opinion)
let e1: HTMLInputElement; // type of variable
e1.checked = true;

// 2nd (sometimes a good option too)    
let e2 = document.getElementById('myInput');
(<HTMLInputElement>e2).checked = true; // "hint" the type to TypeScript

// 3rd (a hack that may come handy sometimes)
let e3 = document.getElementById('myInput');
e2['checked'] = true;
```

Comment: `explicit cast` --> Typescript does not have any type cast as in other languages, it is type assertion imho, also based on your code at the runtime if it can't find the element next line will throw the error type assertion will not save.

Comment: You are right. It's just a "hint" that makes TypeScript compiler happy. I'm struggling to find something about it in the spec.