# How to Set checkbox properties in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, checkbox, angular2-forms

I am trying to fetch the checked value of group of checkboxes in a table. I have a situation like

- List all the records in a table with each row having a checkbox

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" value="{{my.id}}" /></td>
```

- I have a checkbox at table header to toggle true/false for all table checkboxes

  `<th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" (click)="changeCheck()" [(ngModel)]="checkAllValue" /></th>`

My code in changeCheck() is as below:

```
changeCheck(): void {        

    var checkedItems = jQuery("#tbPayments input[type='checkbox'][id!=checkAll]");
    for (let item = 0; item < checkedItems.length; item++) {
        console.log(checkedItems[item].checked = true);
    }
}
```

**But typescript throwing an error :
Property 'checked ' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'**

How do i toggle list of checkboxes in my table. Could someone help !

Comment: If you just see the red mark, then I think you can ignore that, see the same question/answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242324/typescript-how-to-tell-that-element-is-checkbox-so-element-checked-is-not-red-u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CheckedItems is typed to the most typed value that it can determine from the jQuery call, HTMLElement.  If you know it is an HTMLInputElement, you should cast it as such:

```
changeCheck(): void {        
    var checkedItems = jQuery("#tbPayments input[type='checkbox'][id!=checkAll]") as HTMLInputElement[];
    for (let item = 0; item < checkedItems.length; item++) {
        console.log(checkedItems[item].checked = true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Cast `HTMLElement` to `HTMLInputElement` which has the `checked` property.

```
for (let item = 0; item < checkedItems.length; item++) {
    console.log((checkedItems[item] as HTMLInputElement).checked = true);
}
```